# Wiring LP5860 LED Matrix Driver to Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino, led, schematics, led-matrix

I am working on a project in which I'm trying to control a matrix of RGB LEDs using an LP5860 matrix LED driver connected to an Arduino Nano. I want to make sure I'm wiring the two together properly, namely VSYNC and VIO_EN pins on the LP5860. I've attached a screenshot of my schematic as well as the diagram from the datasheet I was going off of. I was confused by how some of the wires seem to just go into the MCU in the datasheet diagram. Also is there a reason I should use 5V over 3.3V, given the LED driver can take both? Thanks.

[image: My Schematic (arduino on left, LED driver on right]

[image: Diagram from LP5860 datasheet I was copying from]